# Tag Removal Request: maven-exec-plugin

Tags: support, tags, burninate-request

The tag [maven-exec-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-exec-plugin) should be removed. This is not an actual plugin in Maven, and in fact is an invalid synonym of the correct tag, [exec-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/exec-maven-plugin).

This is a common misnomer among developers, and we should encourage correct terminology (and tagging) by not making the incorrect tag available.

I'm happy to retag all 10 existing questions to use the [exec-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/exec-maven-plugin) tag so that there aren't any remaining questions with this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But... that's what synonyms are for. Common different names, common misspelling, other ways to write, etc.

I think a synonym is more correct than removing the tag altogether (mainly because there's nothing for preventing it from being created again).

Comment: I'd agree with a synonym setup as well, I just don't have the reputation yet to propose it :) We can see if, over time, the usage of the incorrect tag drops enough to be worth killing it.

Comment: And, more to your point, rather than deleting, if I simply retag the existing questions, the system should remove the incorrect tag within a day or so, correct? I'm fine with that if folks agree -- I'll do the work.

Comment: @PeterMularien: Yes, but then if someone else misspell it again, the problem returns. Synonymizing it the best course of action IMHO.

Comment: Great, we can close this question, then, and I'll retag as appropriate. Can I file a meta request to synonymize the tag, as I don't have the reputation yet?

Comment: @PeterMularien: Yes, you can.